# Multiple applicable methods

Tags: c#

Consider two methods with same name, but different parameters:

```cs
private void Method(int number) => Debug.WriteLine("I'm method 01");

private void Method(int number, string name = "") => Debug.WriteLine("I'm method 02");
```

Theoretically if we call `Method(0);`, both methods are applicable. There are no errors/warnings.

Debugging shows that the compiler takes the *method 01* - is there any rule for that?

Is there no danger that *method 02* gets invoked?

Comment: The most specific method.

Comment: There is a specific language in the spec that says what to do in this scenario. See the answer to the duplicate question for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# specification explains at length exactly how overload resolution works.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#better-function-member) for precise details.

C# is not a random language; every possible piece of code either has a spec-defined meaning (which will never change) or will give a compiler error.

Comment: 'Overload resolution' - I knew I was missing something. Thanks